It teaches you what you shouldn’t be doing in the real world
It teaches you what you shouldn’t be doing in the real world.
Does this sentence say that It teaches you [something]
=> sort of learning for the real world / similar to "it teaches you how to deal with the real world.
Or does it mean that it teaches me something, which is bad to me, and you should also avoid doing this?

Choice B. Aside from cartoons and such, there's the real world. In this world, you should be kind, and you shouldn't be greedy. In a joke or a movie, maybe greed is good, but not in life. Stories show bad things so you see that you should avoid them outside the story.

If I understand right, choice A. It means "It gives an example of something bad, and shows why that's bad". It doesn't mean, for instance, "It teaches you lockpicking, but you could get in trouble if you use lockpicking in the real world".

Could you provide more context about where you saw this? Was it in a book? A TV show? An article? Which one? What is the sentence referring to and what was being discussed more broadly? That will help us answer your question
